# times the read & write operations for a file

Tags: java, netbeans

i am trying to find a way to  Create a class and associated methods that times the read / write operations, displaying the results to the console.
i looked everywhere but i didnt find any thing ((
is it possible to do it ? if so , how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this :

```
long readMethodStartTime = System.nanoTime();
readMethod();
long readMethodEndTime = System.nanoTime();

long readMethodDuration = readMethodEndTime - readMethodStartTime ;
System.out.println("Time taken for readMethod to execute: " + readMethodDuration);
```

and similarly for write methods.